# Optimizing Fleury's algorithm to work in O(|V|+|E|)

Tags: algorithms, graphs, eulerian-paths

The time complexity of Fleury's algorithm is $O(|E|^2)$ because for each edge I have to check whether it is a bridge or not and that takes $O(|V|+|E|)$ time. But, instead of that if I store my bridges in a hash table by a traversal at the beginning and then print the Eulerian tour (checking for each bridge in $O(1)$ using the hash table), the overall time complexity would be $O(|V|+|E|)$. So, will this optimization be useful? If yes, why is it not included in Fleury's algorithm?

In addition, which algorithm is used in practice to print an Eulerian path (not Eulerian cycle, I know that can be done in $O(|V|+|E|)$ using Hierholzer's algorithm)?

I am more interested in theoretical analysis (whether this optimization would be useful) rather than actual implementation.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a bridge in current graph may not be a bridge in the primary graph. Note Fleury's Algorithm deletes an edge after you pass it.

Consider the following graph:

[image]

You start at $A$, then move to $B$ and delete the edge $AB$.

[image]

Now $BE$ becomes a bridge so the algorithm then chooses $BC$. However, $BE$ is not a bridge in the primary graph, so you cannot detect it in advance.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)

> If there are no vertices of odd degree, all Eulerian trails are
>   circuits. If there are exactly two vertices of odd degree, all
>   Eulerian trails start at one of them and end at the other.

So finding an Eulerian trail is essentially the same as finding a cycle (if there are exactly two vertices of odd degree, add an edge connecting them and find an Eulerian cycle in the new graph).